# What is the entry point in a namespace extension for delete operation?

Tags: windows, com, windows-shell, shell-extensions

**Background:**
I am implementing a namespace extension to provide a virtual view of files and folders on a server. I started with a Microsoft SDK sample explorerdataprovider. I modified the enumeration logic and changed menu items to suit my requirements.

**Problem:**
In the `IShellFolder::GetAttributesOf()` function, I mark the item with the flags `SFGAO_CANDELETE|SFGAO_CANRENAME`. It calls `IShellFolder::SetNameOf()` when a rename is attempted. But when I attempt a delete operation (by pressing the delete key), I see no interfaces available in `IShellFolder`, which seems to be called for handling delete.

**Note:**
I can add my own menu item in the context menu to handle this, but it will not be called if delete is initiated using the keyboard, and the user will not see the standard dialog of "Are you sure you want to delete this?".

Please advise me how to handle delete in the namespace extension.

Comment: This has been done before of course, google "shell namespace extension delete operation".  First hit looks like a way to head in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

I think actually manipulating the data in a folder is done via its [IStorage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380015%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface.

It has a method called `DestroyElement`.

Comment: I think IStorage does not belong to the Shell Interfaces. Explorer does not call a QueryInterface asking for IID_IStorage.

Comment: Ah, I may have been confused by zip folders, which implement it.

Comment: @MadhusudanNarayan Wait, would explorer even attempt to QueryInterface IStorage, if an extension's flags (the ones from IShellFolder.GetAttributesOf) don't contain `SFGAO_STORAGE`? Also, according to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/09/01/10204404.aspx maybe it could be called through `IContextMenu::InvokeCommand()`.